# Removing redundant rows from db table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table like the following (bad design I know, but there are a ton of rows like this):

```
person1    |    person2     |    counselor
Jane Doe   |    John Doe    |    Mary Smith
John Doe   |    Jane Doe    |    Mary Smith
Frank Jones|    Ann Jones   |    Tom Jones
Ann Jones  |    Frank Jones |    Tom Jones
```

I'm trying to figure out how to just select one of the 'unique' rows so that a result would look like:

```
person1    |    person2     |    counselor
Jane Doe   |    John Doe    |    Mary Smith
Frank Jones|    Ann Jones   |    Tom Jones
```

I've tried various things like `SELECT distinct` and `SELECT MIN(person1)`, etc., but am striking out.

Answer (score 0):

You will have 6 permutations of (person1,person2,counselor) and you can use `union` with all of them. Finally use a `where` clause so only one row per combination will be returned.

[Fiddle with sample data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eff96/2)

```
select * from (
select person1,person2,counselor 
from tablename
union 
select person1,counselor,person2 
from tablename
union
select person2,person1,counselor 
from tablename
union
select person2,counselor,person1
from tablename
union
select counselor,person2,person1
from tablename
union
select counselor,person1,person2
from tablename) t
where person1 < person2 and person2 < counselor
```

Comment: I would suggest only first two permutation as a base answer and the 6 permutation as a bonus case. Looks like the conselour is the same and the input error is who is frist `person1` or `person2`

Answer (score 0):

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0262b/1)

I include a case where no reverse duplicated and also another case where `person1 = person2`, also include `P2.*` in select just for debug.

```
SELECT P1.person1, P1.person2, P1.counselor, P2.*
FROM patient P1
LEFT JOIN patient P2
       ON P1.person1 = P2.person2
      AND P1.person2 = P2.person1
      AND P1.counselor = P2.counselor
WHERE 
   concat(P1.person1, P1.person2) <= concat(P2.person1, P2.person2)
OR P2.person1 is null
```

When `P2 is NULL` mean there isn't a reverse combination of `person1, person2`

But when the combination exists only choose the smaller one as string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

```
With ranked_records AS
(
   select *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By person1, person2, counselor 
    Order By person) [ranked] 
    from address
)
select * from ranked_records
where ranked > 1
```

For more [detail](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1098/delete-duplicate-records-in-sql-for-specific-columns), like how to delete latest records and keep the older one.

For MySql and if you have Id, try this:

```
DELETE A1
From Address A1
Where Exists (Select * From Address A2 
    Where A2.person1= A1.person1
    AND A2.person2 = A1.person2
    AND A2.counselor = A1.counselor 
    AND A1.AddressID > A2.AddressID)
```

Comment: The question tag is `MYSQL` so no `CTE` or `ROW_NUMBER`. And shouldn't be `rank = 1` ??

Comment: Sorry I never used mysql

Comment: I will have to try it. But does double `person1` works or is a typo?  `Partition By person1, person1`

Comment: I dont see any `address_id` on OP data

Comment: That's what I said, if you have Id only then logic will work.